# Tried everything : Still how can I reduce my apk size ?

Tags: android, performance, proguard, lint

How can I reduce my apk size more efficiently ? I know this is a frequently asked question but I didn't get much help with the resources available.

- I have tried "lint" from Android Studio, it removed several resources but the apk size has not shrinked that much.
- I have used "PngCrush" to compress png files, but it did not helped much (Only 150Kb reduced). Is there any better solution for reducing png file sizes ?
- I am now opting to use ProGuard. Is it safe ? What amount of size will it be able to deduct from my apk ?
- My APK size is currently 17 MB, I want to bring it down to less than 10 MB. Are there other solutions available ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to proguard your apk for size and code decompile, set minifyEnabled true in build gradle file. may i know you have any video file in your app

Comment: @MageshPandian, No, I dont have any audio & video file in my app. I will apply proguard and let you know the modified apk size. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: Did you use big library like Google Play Service? Did you enable multidex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following methods :

> 1) use proguard : set minifyEnabled true
>
> 2) Remove unused resources :  set shrinkResources true
>
> 3) Remove everything that you are not using
>
> 4) If you are using librarires ,try finding the snippet that you are
>   really using,if you dont find any such version,try fiddling with the
>   required class directly in your app instead of importing whole library
>
> 5) Use vector drawable instead of pngs for your small icons and
>   drawables
>
> 6) Reduce png images clarity to point where it have same
>   effect to human eye ,while its size is reduced heavily
>
> 7) Try generating resources or draws on runtime instead of storing it before
>   hand

Progaurd is totally safe,make sure you keep a raw backup of ur work before using proguard ,also use proper rules for all libraries and other important resources and code , before you activate proguard.Generally libraries provided default proguard rules for thier libraries

Comment: @tahsinRupam , can u please also Upvote , ty for accepting , hope it helped

Comment: Yes, I definitely will if you help me to fix this. My app keeps crashing after implementing proguard. Here is the error :-

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/ldap/LdapName;

Comment: you have screwed up library , but activating proguard before add all the necesary rules

Answer (score 2):

Proguard should be the way to go because it removes the unused code as well as renames the variable/method name to something like a,b,c,aa,ab.

What amount can be reduced? It depends. My situation is a 10M apk was reduced to 8M using Proguard.

Is it safe? One of the purpose of Proguard is that it obfuscate the code, making it hard for reverse engineering.